# Is the exponential object $B^A$ related to $hom_C(A,B)$?

Tags: category-theory

In category $Set$, do $B^A$ and $hom_{Set}(A,B)$ mean the same: the set of all the functions from $A$ to $B$?

In a category $C$, is the exponential object $B^A$ of objects $A$ and $B$ related to $hom_C(A,B)$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

For a cartesian closed category, at least, we have $$\mathsf{Hom}(A,B)\cong\mathsf{Hom}(1\times A,B)\cong\mathsf{Hom}(1,B^A)$$ where $1$ is the terminal object. This would be described as the arrows $A\to B$ correspond to the *global elements* (or global points) of $B^A$ (which just means the arrows $1\to B^A$).

Crucially, however, in most categories (with $\mathbf{Set}$ being the main exception) an object isn't determined by its global elements. For example, in the category of [$M$-sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup_action) for a monoid $M$, an arrow $1\to (X,\alpha)$ is an element of $X$ such that $\alpha(m,x)=x$ for all $m\in M$. There are plenty of non-trivial $M$-sets where this is *never* true meaning there are *no* global elements. For example, consider the action of $\mathbb N$ on itself via addition.

The upshot is that there can be a lot more going on in $B^A$ than the global elements (i.e. the morphism $A\to B$) suggest. (It's also possible to define $B^A$ in a category that doesn't have a terminal object.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Intuitively, the exponential object $B^A$ is somehow the "object version" of $Hom(A,B)$ - or at least can be interpreted as such *after* we add to the picture a morphism satisfying an appropriate universal property.

Specifically, remember that (fixing $A,B$) the *(up to iso)* exponential $B^A$ is an object $X$ together with an *evaluation morphism* $$ev: X\times A\rightarrow B$$ (we're working in a category with finite products, so this in fact makes sense) such that for any object $U$ and any morphism $m:U\times A\rightarrow B$ there is a unique map $h: U\rightarrow X$ such that the appropriate diagram commutes.

Roughly speaking, in this definition we're viewing $m$ as a "$U$-indexed family" of maps from $A$ to $B$ (after de-Currying, $m$ takes an element of $U$ and outputs a map from $A$ to $B$); saying that $X$ represents the collection of maps from $A$ to $B$ says that we can "interpret" $U$ in $X$ appropriately (this is our $h$).

---

EDIT: **That said**, don't push this sort of set-theoretic analogy too far - basic intuitions about how sets work can break down in natural categories, per Derek Elkins' answer.

Comment: This is nifty way to look at things; way to go Noah! ^_^